# How do I create a +1 button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, counting, tkinter-entry

**I am writing a baseball counting program. I have a label for walks and strikeouts. To the side of those labels I have buttons with the text "+1". I want the buttons to be able to change and print the number of walks and strikeouts every time I click the +1 buttons. I just need some ideas to help get started. Here is my code for clarification: **

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import COMMAND, X


global walk_counter
walk_counter = 0

global strikeout_counter
strikeout_counter = 0

def main(): # This is the main function
    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.master.title("Random Title")
    frame.pack(padx=4, pady=3, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    populate_boxes(frame)
    root.mainloop()

def populate_boxes(frame):
    walks_label = tk.Label(frame, text="BB:")
    walks_entry = tk.Label(frame, width=4)
    walks_button = tk.Button(frame,text="+1")
    strikeouts_label = tk.Label(frame,text="Strikeouts:")
    strikeouts_entry = tk.Label(frame,width=4)
    strikeouts_button = tk.Button(frame,text="+1")

    walks_label.place(x=200,y=500)
    walks_entry.place(x=250,y=500)
    walks_button.place(x=300,y=500)
    strikeouts_label.place(x=400,y=500)
    strikeouts_entry.place(x=450,y=500)
    strikeouts_button.place(x=500,y=500)

    def add_more_walks():
        global walk_counter
        walk_counter += 1
        walks_entry.config(text = walk_counter)
    add_more_walks()

main()
```

Comment: Did you know that you can assign a function to `command` option of a `Button`?  The function will be executed whenever the button is clicked, so you can increase the required counter inside that function.

Comment: I am currently doing that, know my function isn't cooperating. Here is the output: 
def add_more_walks():
        walk_counter = 0
        addition = walk_counter +=1
        walks_entry.config(text = addition)

Comment: The `add_more_walks()` in your question works fine.  Just move it to the beginning of `populate_boxes()` and set `command=add_more_walks` to `walks_button`.